# Is my database schema fully normalized?

Tags: database, design-patterns

#### Product

```
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------------+
|Field           |  Type          |  Null  |  Key  | Default  |  Extra         |
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------------+
|id              |  int(11)       |  No    |  PRI  | Null     | auto_increment | 
|modelNumber     |  varchar(150)  |  No    |       |          |                |
|manufacturer_id |  int(11)       |  No    |       |          |                |
|name            |  varchar(100)  |  No    |       |          |                |
|department_id   |  int(11)       |  No    |       |          |                |
|class_id        |  int(11)       |  No    |       |          |                |
|subclass_id     |  int(11)       |  No    |       |          |                |
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------------+
```

#### Department_id

```
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+
|Field          | Type           | Null   | Key   | Default  | Extra       |
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+
|department_id  | int(11)        |        |  PRI  |          |             |
|name           | varchar(100)   |        |       |          |             |
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

#### Manufacturer

```
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+---------------+
|Field           | Type           | Null   | Key   | Default  | Extra         |
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+---------------+
|manufacturer_id | int(11)        |        |  PRI  |          |               |
|name            | varchar(100)   |        |       |          |               |     
+----------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+---------------+
```

#### Class

```
+-----------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------+
|Field      | Type           | Null   | Key   | Default  | Extra    |
+-----------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------+
|class_id   | int(11)        |        | PRI   |          |          |
|name       | varchar(100)   |        |       |          |          |
+-----------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+----------+
```

#### Subclass

```
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+------------+
|Field          | Type           | Null   | Key   | Default  | Extra      |
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+------------+
|subclass_id    | int(11)        |        |  PRI  |          |            |
|name           | varchar(100)   |        |       |          |            |
+---------------+----------------+--------+-------+----------+------------+
```

I do not have full control over how I obtain the data, as I am getting a large amount of data via XML. I need to create a database that will allow me to expand.

Comment: It looks pretty close - but are class and subclass related?

Comment: Class is the Category of the product, and subclass is the subcategory of the product. So in theory I think, yes they are related. Ultimately, As users navigate the website, the path to a product of a subclass will be found by first going to department, then class, then subclass. Unless I provide a direct link to sub classes, or the users search for a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `classid` and `subclassid` are not related,it is in `3nf` and not in `BCNF` because `modelNumber` is not a `dependency` on `id`. but if they are related its not even in `3nf`